# How to check value from one array if exists

Tags: javascript, angular

I  have 2 arrays.  one is costHeadArray which  is as

```
[
  {
   "label":"Flight",
   "value":"179daf5f-2f89-1d12-40a2-e91a6a732774"
  }
]
```

I  am iterating response. My object value is as

```
{
  taxInvoiceId: "b1b4d9ec-f20c-4a33-94c1-af7589e7b15a", 
  enquiryId: "3db0b4a8-5ab1-4c31-861a-73df36205716", 
  costHeadId: "179daf5f-2f89-1d12-40a2-e91a6a732774", 
  costSheetId: "01edd4a1-f1ad-a836-3a19-3a28271f1b57", 
  ...
}
```

Now in same iteration, I  need to check if costHeadArray value matches value in object. costHeadArray can have multiple json objects. only if value in costHeadArray matches with object then i need to enable flag. I tried using includes but it dont works . might be I am doing something wrong

My code

```
   this.airInvoiceService.getTaxInvoiceLog(this.enquiryId).subscribe(
            response => {
                this.taxInvoiceLogs.unshift(...response);
                for(const a of response) {
                    //   {taxInvoiceId: "b1b4d9ec-f20c-4a33-94c1-af7589e7b15a", enquiryId: "3db0b4a8-5ab1-4c31-861a-73df36205716", enquiryRefId: "MTPL-2021-000074", costHeadId: "179daf5f-2f89-1d12-40a2-e91a6a732774", costSheetId: "01edd4a1-f1ad-a836-3a19-3a28271f1b57", …}
                    console.log(a);
                
                   
                    //[{"label":"Flight","value":"e9bf7aa2-c730-8175-1cec-afcd239b0dff"}]
                   console.log(JSON.stringify(this.costHeadArray));

                   console.log(a.costHeadId);

                    if (Object.values(a).includes(this.costHeadArray)){
                        console.log('Gokul');
                    }

                    if (this.costHeadArray.includes(a.costHeadId)) {
                        console.log('Sam');
                        this.hideForm =  true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you trying to check by keys? Or why not consider doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I have write simple script for you, please have a look, I hope it will help you

```js
let costHeadArray = [
  {
   "label":"Flight",
   "value":"179daf5f-2f89-1d12-40a2-e91a6a732774"
  }
];

let myObject = {
  taxInvoiceId: "b1b4d9ec-f20c-4a33-94c1-af7589e7b15a", 
  enquiryId: "3db0b4a8-5ab1-4c31-861a-73df36205716", 
  costHeadId: "179daf5f-2f89-1d12-40a2-e91a6a732774", 
  costSheetId: "01edd4a1-f1ad-a836-3a19-3a28271f1b57", 
}


let hasCostHeadValue = costHeadArray.find(o => o.value == myObject.costHeadId) != null;

console.log(hasCostHeadValue);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Update your method like this.

```js
this.airInvoiceService.getTaxInvoiceLog(this.enquiryId).subscribe(
  response => {
    
    this.taxInvoiceLogs.unshift(...response);
    for(const a of response) {
      //   {taxInvoiceId: "b1b4d9ec-f20c-4a33-94c1-af7589e7b15a", enquiryId: "3db0b4a8-5ab1-4c31-861a-73df36205716", enquiryRefId: "MTPL-2021-000074", costHeadId: "179daf5f-2f89-1d12-40a2-e91a6a732774", costSheetId: "01edd4a1-f1ad-a836-3a19-3a28271f1b57", …}
      console.log(a);                
                   
      //[{"label":"Flight","value":"e9bf7aa2-c730-8175-1cec-afcd239b0dff"}]
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.costHeadArray));

      console.log(a.costHeadId);
      
      let hasCostHeadValue = this.costHeadArray.find(o => o.value == a.costHeadId) != null;
      if(hasConstHeadValue){

      } else {

      }  

      // if (Object.values(a).includes(this.costHeadArray)){
         // console.log('Gokul');
      // }

      // if (this.costHeadArray.includes(a.costHeadId)) {
        // console.log('Sam');
        // this.hideForm =  true;
      //}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.includes` is comparing the array items by reference, not by value, thus:

For the array `const values = [ {value: 1}, { value: 2} ]`

- `values.includes(values[0])` will return true, because it re-uses the same `{value:1}`-object as the array and both objects have same reference ID.
- `values.includes({value: 1})` will return false, because the objects have the same content but *different* references.

You can use [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) instead:

```js
const search = {value: 1};
const includes = values.findIndex(item => item.value === search.value) >= 0;
```